# Simple database-like collection class in Java

Tags: java, database, algorithm, data-structures, collections

The problem: Maintain a bidirectional many-to-one relationship among java objects.

Something like the Google/Commons Collections bidi maps, but I want to *allow* duplicate values on the forward side, and have *sets* of the forward keys as the reverse side values.
Used something like this:

```
// maintaining disjoint areas on a gameboard. Location is a space on the
// gameboard; Regions refer to disjoint collections of Locations.

MagicalManyToOneMap<Location, Region> forward = // the game universe
Map<Region, <Set<Location>>> inverse = forward.getInverse(); // live, not a copy
Location parkplace = Game.chooseSomeLocation(...);
Region mine = forward.get(parkplace); // assume !null; should be O(log n)
Region other = Game.getSomeOtherRegion(...);
// moving a Location from one Region to another:
forward.put(parkplace, other);
// or equivalently:
inverse.get(other).add(parkplace); // should also be O(log n) or so
// expected consistency:
assert ! inverse.get(mine).contains(parkplace);
assert forward.get(parkplace) == other;
// and this should be fast, not iterate every possible location just to filter for mine:
for (Location l : mine) { /* do something clever */ }
```

The simple java approaches are: 1. To maintain only one side of the relationship, either as a `Map<Location, Region>` or a `Map<Region, Set<Location>>`, and collect the inverse relationship by iteration when needed; Or, 2. To make a wrapper that maintains both sides' Maps, and intercept all mutating calls to keep both sides in sync.

1 is O(n) instead of O(log n), which is becoming a problem. I started in on 2 and was in the weeds straightaway. (Know how many different ways there are to alter a Map entry?)

This is almost trivial in the sql world (Location table gets an indexed RegionID column). Is there something obvious I'm missing that makes it trivial for normal objects?

Comment: I'm reluctant to put this as an answer because I don't know what you're actually doing, but for what its worth, I think you're just using the wrong data structure. What you describe isn't a map or a set, its a graph where all of the vertices are adjacent to any number of other vertices. You'll get a better programming model + runtime by using a proper graph data structure rather than glue together sets and maps haphazardly.

Comment: Probably. All I'm after from Maps and Sets is the very basic semantics and the log-n performance. If a better structure provides a vaguely map-ish "view" of things, perfect.
Am exploring http://jung.sourceforge.net/ thanks to a now-deleted answer and it looks promising.

Comment: Is the cost of insertions important to you? (Also, do you mean otherset in that last line?)

Comment: yep. A partition of Locations into disjoint Regions is a trial solution for a backtracking puzzle solver, so there could be O(2^n) of them (I pare this down significantly.) Deletion isn't an issue though.

I clarified the code a bit too - yes, I was thinking a Location should map straight to its Region (just a tag, really), and a Region map back to a Collection of its Locations. The only Set quality I need in that direction is fast iteration; the forward mapping is already a fast membership test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could achieve what you need with the following two classes.   While it does involve two maps, they are not exposed to the outside world, so there shouldn't be a way for them to get out of sync.  As for storing the same "fact" twice, I don't think you'll get around that in any efficient implementation, whether the fact is stored twice explicitly as it is here, or implicitly as it would be when your database creates an index to make joins more efficient on your 2 tables.  you can add new things to the magicset and it will update both mappings, or you can add things to the magicmapper, which will then update the inverse map auotmatically.  The girlfriend is calling me to bed now so I cannot run this through a compiler - it should be enough to get you started. what puzzle are you trying to solve?

```
public class MagicSet<L> {
   private Map<L,R> forward;
   private R r;
   private Set<L> set;

   public MagicSet<L>(Map forward, R r) {
       this.forward = map;
       this.r = r;
       this.set = new HashSet<L>();
   }

   public void add(L l) {
       set.add(l);
       forward.put(l,r);
   }

   public void remove(L l) {
       set.remove(l);
       forward.remove(l);
   }

   public int size() {
       return set.size();
   }

   public in contains(L l){
       return set.contains(l);
   }

   // caution, do not use the remove method from this iterator. if this class was going
   // to be reused often you would want to return a wrapped iterator that handled the remove method properly.  In fact, if you did that, i think you could then extend AbstractSet and MagicSet would then fully implement java.util.Set.
   public Iterator iterator() {
       return set.iterator();  
   }
}



public class MagicMapper<L,R> { // note that it doesn't implement Map, though it could with some extra work.  I don't get the impression you need that though.
 private Map<L,R> forward;
 private Map<R,MagicSet<L>> inverse;

 public MagicMapper<L,R>() {
       forward = new HashMap<L,R>;
       inverse = new HashMap<R,<MagicSet<L>>;
 }


 public R getForward(L key) {
       return forward.get(key);
 }


 public Set<L> getBackward(R key) {
       return inverse.get(key);  // this assumes you want a null if
                               // you try to use a key that has no mapping.  otherwise you'd return a blank MagicSet
 }

 public void put (L l, R r) {

       R oldVal = forward.get(l);

       // if the L had already belonged to an R, we need to undo that mapping
       MagicSet<L> oldSet = inverse.get(oldVal);

       if (oldSet != null) {oldSet.remove(l);}

       // now get the set the R belongs to, and add it.
       MagicSet<L> newSet = inverse.get(l);

       if (newSet == null) {
               newSet = new MagicSet<L>(forward, r);
               inverse.put(r,newSet);
       }
       newSet.add(l);  // magically updates the "forward" map
 }


}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. That is indeed along the lines of my failed attempt #2. I should probably have tried taking smaller bites.

The puzzle under investigation is Nurikabe - I'm making an editor for my own use to make quality Nurikabe puzzles (the autogenerated ones on puzzle-nurikabe.com are meh) and for this I need a fast solver, to check my work and estimate difficulty.

Comment: If for some reason you really really wanted these to implement the java.util Set and Map interfaces, you should read the javadoc on AbstractMap and AbstractSet - they do some of the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I might misunderstand your model, but if your Location and Region have correct equals() and hashCode() implemented, then the set of Location -> Region is just a classical simple Map implementation (multiple distinct keys can point to the same object value). The Region -> Set of Location is a Multimap (available in Google Coll.). You could compose your own class with the proper add/remove methods to manipulate both submaps.

Maybe an overkill, but you could also use in-memory sql server (HSQLDB, etc). It allows you to create index on many columns.

Comment: Yeah, composing out of two submaps is what I'm trying to avoid. It stores the same "fact" twice ("A is in B" and "B contains A"), and there are a *lot* of ways to modify a map entry that I'd have to catch to keep the two consistent. I may well wind up doing the sql thing with sqlite or the like, if I don't run across a better way using a data structure new to me.

Comment: If it was me, I'd cobble together whatever internal mess of `Set`s and `Map`s I thought would work, write some tests against the external interface, and figure on replacing the internals later if I happened to run across a better data structure. (And I wouldn't make the external interface any more general than I need it to be.)

Can't you encapsulate the submaps so they're not accessible from outside your interface, and never expose the actual map entries? Then you're just using the submaps for bookkeeping, and you don't really have to "catch" anything.